# Name of the contrasting text effect

Tags: terminology, contrast, lighting-effects

I'm looking for a name for the effect when there's a layer over another layer so that one of them always adjusts so that it has always the opposite shade of spectrum. So I want a title to look black on white backgroundand black on white background.

[image: the OA poster]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top layer has the blending mode 'difference'. I don't think there's an official name, but I'd call it a 'difference effect'.

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be, Inverted? Negative?

The way I would do this is taking te text as a mask and **invert** the curves, so the image is a **negative**.